# Sonar - Store a copy - Mutable members should not be stored or returned directly

Tags: java, arraylist, sonarqube, mutable

I have a list which is a private member in my class.
I have used getter and setter to get and set the values.
SOnar throws an error - Mutable members should not be stored or returned directly.

For example: ABC and DEF are two classes.

```
class ABC{
private List<DEF> defList;
public List<DEF> getDefList() { return defList; }
public void setDefList(List<DEF> defList) { this.defList = defList; }
```

After lot of googling and searching, I have understood that the getter can be changed as follows:

```
public List<DEF> getDefList() { return new ArrayList<>(defList); }
```

When i try to use setter similarly,

```
public void setDefList(List<DEF> defList) { this.defList.addAll(defList); }
```

then the variable starts showing

```
'private field 'defList' is never assigned.
```

May I know the correct way to do when it is a list, (a list of another class)

Note: Both the answers from Prasad Karunagoda and Leo Aso  works. I cant mark both as accepted answer. So having a note here

Comment: If you do `this.defList.addAll(defList);` the `defList` is null. You need to create a List before adding elements to it.

Comment: But then how did it work when it was simple this.defList = defList?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The warning is because you did not give the field an initial value. This is how you should implement the code to ensure immutability using `java.util.Collections`.

```
class ABC {
    private List<DEF> defList = Collections.emptyList();

    public List<DEF> getDefList() { 
        return defList;
    }

    public void setDefList(List<DEF> defList) {
        // defensively copy, then make immutable
        defList = new ArrayList<>(defList);
        this.defList = Collections.unmodifiableList(defList);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick Reply. Then in the getter it should be return Collections.unmodifiableList(defList) ??

Comment: It is worth noting that `DEF` class needs to be immutable as well. Otherwise some other class could get the list and change objects inside it. Objects in `abc.defList` would change as well.

Comment: @pgman you don't need to wrap the field in an `unmodifiableList` again in the getter, because you already made the field itself immutable in the setter.

Comment: Incase if it is a Date, then how the error 'Mutable members should not be stored or returned directly' can be resolved?

Comment: Date is mutable (and deprecated), but in Java 8 there is the `java.time` package with immutable classes like LocalDateTime and ZonedDateTime. You can look it up on Google to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is better not to add additional restrictions (immutability) to the `List` returned from the getter. If you do that, clients using your `List` will not be able sort it for example.

So, my recommended approach is this:

```
public class ABC {
  private List<DEF> defList = new ArrayList<>();

  public List<DEF> getDefList() {
    return new ArrayList<>(defList);
  }

  public void setDefList(List<DEF> defList) {
    if (defList == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter defList is null");
    this.defList.clear();
    this.defList.addAll(defList);
  }
}
```

From design perspective, an even better API for `ABC` class would be:

```
public List<DEF> getDefList()
public void clearDefList()
public void addAllDefs(List<DEF> defs) // Or method name appendDefs
```

Comment: I have used the same, but the Problem is when i use it like this, it Shows 'private field defList' is never assigned

Comment: In your code, have you initialized `defList` field like `private List<DEF> defList = new ArrayList<>();` or do you only have `private List<DEF> defList;`?

Comment: Oh my mistake. sorry. Yes, i wasnt using = new ArrayList<>()

Comment: one clarification... is this.defList.clear() important here?

Comment: Yes, otherwise DEF objects passed in will be appended to the existing list. E.g. if `this.defList` originally has 3 objects and 4 objects are passed in as the parameter, at the end there will be 7 objects in `this.defList`.

Comment: what if am using setter to add in a loop? then everytime Clearing it wouldnt have all items Right? so as u mentioned i can used three Methods. And clear it first time and then just use addAllDefs()?? is my understanding clear?

Comment: Yes, but these things depend on the usage of the class. So, we have to design the APIs of a class based on the usage and semantic meaning.

Comment: Just one more clarification. Can i have  this.defList = new ArrayList<>(defList);
in setter?? Along with return new ArrayList<>(defList); in getter?? I mean both the Methods using new ArrayList<>() ??

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But I feel it is an unnecessary creation of an `ArrayLisy` object in the setter.

Comment: Thx. What if the vlue passed is null. Then setter wont work. As null isnt supported.

Comment: @pgman, yes, `null` validation was not there. I just added it to my answer now.

Comment: cool … Just wanted to Mention so that if any other tries it, would be aware of this condition

Comment: @PrasadKarunagoda "If you do that, clients using your List will not be able sort it for example." That's the idea. Clients should not, generally speaking, be directly modifying private fields of other objects. Imagine if different clients are running in multiple threads! A client that wants a sorted list needs to make a copy.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ABC {
    private List<DEF> defList = Collections.emptyList();

    public List<DEF> getDefList() { 
        List<DEF> defListCopy = new ArrayList();
        if(defList != null){
         defListCopy = Collections.unmodifiableList(defList);
        }
        return defListCopy;
    }

    public void setDefList(final List<DEF> defList) {
        this.defList = Optional.ofNullable(defList).orElse(new ArrayList<>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).